# Covariance of the number of tasks given to two employees

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, covariance

I stumbled upon the following question:
A company has a manager and $n \geq 3$ employees. The manager flips a coin $2n$ times: each time he flips heads he gives one task to one of his employees, chosen randomly and uniformly. We denote $X_i$ as the number of tasks given to employee number $i$. Find $Cov(X_1,X_2)$.

My attempt: 
At first I calculated $\forall_{1\leq i \leq n}.\mathbb{E}[X_i]$. 
$\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \sum_\limits{k=0}^{2n}\mathbb{E}[X_i|Number ~of~heads=k] \mathbb{P}(Number ~of~heads=k) = \sum_\limits{k=0}^{2n} \frac{k}{n} {2n \choose k}(\frac{1}{2})^{2n} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_\limits{k=0}^{2n} k {2n \choose k} (\frac{1}{2})^{2n} = \frac{1}{n} \mathbb{E}[Number~of~heads] = 1$ 
So we have $Cov(X_1, X_2) = \mathbb{E}[X_1X_2]-\mathbb{E}[X_1]\mathbb{E}[X_2]=\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2]-1$. I got stuck from here, failing to calculate $\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2]$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would work out the covariance if the manager flips once  - the cases are $(0,0), (1,0), (0,1)$ with different probabilities -  and then note that each flip is independent

Comment: PS: Just use $N$ as the count for heads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define the random variables
$$I_k = 
\begin{cases}
1, \quad \text{if employee 1 got the $k$-th task} \\
0, \quad \text{if he didn't}
\end{cases}
$$
And similarly we define $J_\ell$ for employee $2$.
Notice that
$$
X_1 = \sum_{k=1}^{2n} I_k
\quad \text{and} \quad
X_2 = \sum_{\ell=1}^{2n} J_\ell.
$$
By linearity of the covariance, we have
$$
\rm{Cov}(X_1, X_2)
= \rm{Cov}\left(
  \sum_{k=1}^{2n} I_k,
  \sum_{\ell=1}^{2n} J_\ell
\right)
= \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \sum_{\ell=1}^{2n} \rm{Cov}(I_k, J_\ell).
\tag{1}\label{full cov}
$$

Observe that, because the coin flips are independent, $I_k$ is independent of $J_\ell$ if $k \neq \ell$ and, hence, $\rm{Cov}(I_k, J_\ell) = 0$ in that case.
Therefore, (\ref{full cov}) reduces to
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \rm{Cov} (I_k, J_k).
$$
Because they are identically distributed for every $k$, this is the same as
$$
2n \cdot \rm{Cov} (I_1, J_1).
$$
Now all we have to do is compute this covariance.
For the individual expectations, we have
$$
\mathbb{E}[J_1] = \mathbb{E}[I_1] = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{2n}.
$$
For the expectation of the product, we know that $I_1 J_1$ is only equal to $1$ if both of them are $1$, otherwise it's $0$. But the probability of that happening is $0$. So $\mathbb{E}[I_1 J_1] = 0$.

Hence,
$$
\rm{Cov} (I_1, J_1) = \mathbb{E}[I_1 J_1] - \mathbb{E}[I_1]\mathbb{E}[J_1] = - \frac{1}{4 n^{2}}.
$$
So,
$$
\rm{Cov}(X_1, X_2) = 2n \cdot \left( - \frac{1}{4n^2} \right) = - \frac{1}{2n}.
$$